# How to validate a new physics theory and keep the credit for it

Tags: soft-question

For the last few years, My friend worked on figuring out the "theory of everything". She is afraid of sharing her theory with well known physicists, because she doesn't want other people to take credit for her idea. So, my here's what I'm wondering:

**1) What is the best way for her to validate her theory with experienced physicists?** and

**2) If the theory ends up being worth publishing, how can she go about publishing it considering the fact that she has no reputation in the field at the moment?**

Comment: And why did she do it?

Comment: Her theory should answer it

Comment: The simplest way to validate her theory was exactly what she did: to tell you the rough situation, so that you asked the question on Physics Stack Exchange, and you have actually listed enough data for the validation to proceed. The answer of the validation is that the theory is nonsense. That answers 1) which makes it unnecessary to answer 2). I can guarantee to you that a person who would find a theory of everything wouldn't describe it as unifying the "field of the big bang" with the "infinitely small" (both of them are nonsense), and moreover, (s)he would know it's not "just" her work.

Comment: By the way, your friend has automatically earned 10 credits according to the rule #12 at http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/crackpot.html - because of her main worry - but I am sure that even your modest description is enough to earn many, many more points in this score. ;-)

Comment: Fine, I've modified my question. I somehow figured out that my question would receive criticism and skepticism. I like Anna's answer the best.

Comment: Lubos: your comment wasn't helpful. First of all, my lack of understanding of physics has made me explain the theory in a wrong way. Of course... I don't know much about it. All there is to know is that her theory, according to her, works at all levels. I forgot to mention that she is a physics teacher.

Comment: What I wanted to find out (and no she didn't ask me to post anything on Stack), is how to help her validate and publish her theory without losing all the credit for it.

Comment: Write a paper, publish it somewhere, even if that is just her website, with a clear google cache date.

Comment: From the comments it is clear that no one here wants to "steal" here theory. I am pretty sure that no physicist would want to steal it. So go ahead tell her to write down the few simple formulas that work well. She is perfectly safe.

Comment: Thanks for the non-useful comment MBN. Even if something sounds to good to be true, that doesn't mean that you have to "ridicule" it. A more appropriate comment would have been: "the chances that her theory would work are extremely slim, therefore, the risk of posting her theory online is very low as well."  How can you be pretty sure that no physicist would want to steal it? Because I didn't manage to explain the situation well in the first place? Because you think it's very improbable that she came up with anything good? In any case, you should stop making sarcastic comments altogether.

Comment: You are reading too much in my comment. I was just saying that from what I see here, no one seems remotely interested, so she would be safe. Also I do believe that physicists are  a good bunch and would not plagiarize here work.

Comment: @Faust: every physicist (and other scientist, I presume) gets asked the sort of question you asked ("how do I promote my theory without it getting stolen" or some variant), and at least 99% of the time, the theory turns out to be either wrong, useless, or already discovered. So experience has conditioned us to dismiss anyone asking this question as a crackpot. Of course the harsh reaction you've gotten was not deserved, but I just want to give you some insight as to why you've gotten these responses. (to be continued)

Comment: (cont) Anyone who is familiar enough with physics to evaluate whether an idea is good or bad should know that it's exceptionally rare, even nearly unheard of, for a qualified physicist to steal someone else's theory outright. The fact that your friend doesn't know that leads us to doubt her credibility by default, although it doesn't mean she won't get a chance to prove herself. Science thrives on the open exchange of ideas, so in all seriousness, anna's answer is right: the best way to avoid having her theory stolen is to publish it widely.

Comment: By the way, the main reason I closed this question is because it's not really about physics, it's about the academic process which all sciences use.

Comment: First send it to viXra.org so that it is publicly archived and any revisions you want to make are independently tracked and recorded. Then submit to a peer reviewed journal. Even if they wont publish she will get some feedback.

Comment: David: I thank you for your answer and honesty. I have to admit that I am the first one to be skeptical about her theory, but that's only normal. When she talked to me about it, I tried to challenge it but my lack of knowledge of physics didn't allow me to challenge it properly. I'll tell her that she should try to put it in writing and publish it informally, just so that there is a way to track it down to her.

Comment: Philip: too bad the question is closed. Your answer rocks!

Comment: @Faust: another option that just occurred to me is the [Independent Research](http://www.physicsforums.com/forumdisplay.php?f=146) subforum of physicsforums.com.

Comment: @Faust: When you write up and put your theory on the web don't forget to tell us. I am curious to see it.

Comment: @Faust I suggest Validation is not what your friend should look for. Better to look for ways that people might find her theory *useful*. Perhaps the person who deserves most credit is the person who explains the theory to her grandmother, or to you. What does credit mean to your friend? I gave up on getting credit for my research long ago because if you don't tell anyone about it you improve it much more slowly. I hope your friend might spread any credit she gets amongst those whose work she uses generously enough that she'll have very little left for herself. Think Oscar acceptance speech.

Comment: I totally agree with you Peter. That's exactly how I see it personnally. I tried convincing her of bringing the debate or the talk on the public place with other physicists or on websites (like physics.SE for instance) but she still refuses. It's hard to know why she doesn't want to do it (fear? shame of rejection? etc). I'm supposed to see her again in a few weeks. I'll try to convince her again. If not, I'll get her to post it somewhere so it can't be "stolen" from her... and see where to go from there :)

Comment: I appreciate the fact that physicists don't necessarily like it when a random person comes to their specialized forum with a question like this one. It's a bit like a newbie going to the grammy awards and asking singers to listen to their new tape (which they claim is the next big hit)

Comment: @PhilipGibbs: Nice advertising : ) .

Comment: @dimension10: arXiv.org gets a free community ad on the site so I have no qualms about mentioning viXra.org when it is a good answer to a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though  I tend to be of the same mind as the comments, I would like to answer, before the question is closed, since comments are limited in character counts.

1st) validation. Validation means that somebody,, in this case the investigator proposing a new theory comes up with hard numbers from the proposed theory and validates them by checking with the accurate data available from elementary particle tables to astronomy ones. i.e. checks predictions against data.

If, for example, the standard model of particle physics does not come out naturally from the new theory, it is invalidated as a theory of everything.

2) if the first stage is passed, and the theory of your friend by some miraculous manner is validated by the existing data up to now,she can publish with her name and address, her theory  and its validation in [the archives](http://arxiv.org/help/faq/index) so there is no way somebody will take the credit from her.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can you prevent the one validating the theory by running the numbers to steal the idea and publish it on his own?

Comment: Is the the theory/theorist able to determine *any* numbers without external help?

Comment: Yes. The theory involves a few simple formulas that surprisingly appear to work well.

Comment: @Faust To validate a Theory Of Everything one should do it by oneself. If one validates that crucial postulates of quantum mechanics which are supported by a plethora of data are included and not violated by   the theory, ditto for the Standard Model of particle physics, ditto for gravity one would have enough confidence to pursue publication. Once the theory is published on the archives with the author's identification it cannot be "stolen". If it needs others to work for the validation it probably belongs to the group of "theories" described by the comments to your question.

Comment: Thanks again for your comments. I wish everybody was this respectful **and** helpful.

Comment: There is no way that theory can contain any new simple formulas that work well or they would have been discovered long ago. Its combinatorically impossible

Comment: I hope that's not true :)

Comment: But really, the first and most important thing to check is whether all the stuff we already know is still in some way or another included in your TOE. Just like Newtonian mechanics are still included in Special Relativity in the limit of, e.g., small velocities.

Comment: This answer is right on: check it and publish on arxiv.org.